# Can I add conditions to LEFT JOIN clauses that aren't part of the join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

It seems to me that both these queries will return the same results:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.key = table2.key AND table2.foo = 1

SELECT * FROM table1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.key = table2.key
  WHERE table2.foo = 1
```

Is that correct? If so, is there any meaningful difference between them?

Comment: yes, there is a difference.the second query is equivalent to an inner join. as you are filtering on the *right* table. The first query is okay. you can add conditions not related to join columns in `ON`.

Comment: no, it is not correct. The second query is effectively converting your join into an `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will **NOT** return the same results.

The first query will include records from table1, even if there is no matching table2 record where foo is 1.

The second query will *not* include records from table1 for which there is no matching table2 record with a foo value of 1.

This kind of pattern (`LEFT JOIN t ON id=id and other='literal'`) is common. For example, in the system I work with most currently we have an `address_master` table that has a `person_id` column for the person matching the address and an `addr_cde` (address code) column telling what kind of address it is (home, work, vacation, etc). So it's common to see a join like this:

```
 LEFT JOIN address_master a ON a.person_id = Person.Id AND a.addr_cde = 'Work'
```

If we moved the `addr_cde = 'Work'` expression to the `WHERE` clause, the query would not show us any person who doesn't have a work address on file, even if we wanted to see the other data for that person.

Answer (score 2):

it's not correct

if we assume below sample data, the results is not same:

```
T1
KEY
---
 1  
 2  

T2
KEY Foo
--- ---
 1  1
 2  4


SELECT * FROM table1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.key = table2.key AND table2.foo = 1

T1.KEY  T2.KEY  T2.Foo
------  ------  ------
1       1       1
2       NULL    Null

SELECT * FROM table1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.key = table2.key
  WHERE table2.foo = 1

T1.KEY  T2.KEY  T2.Foo
------  ------  ------
1       1       1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
The following shows how the 2 queries are different:   

    declare @t1 table(id int);
    insert into @t1 values (1), (2);

    declare @t2 table(id int, col int);
    insert into @t2 values(1,1), (3,1);
```

1. First example--a LEFT join with the Where filter on the right table:

   ```
   select *
   from @t1 t1 
   left join @t2 t2
   on t1.id = t2.id
   where t2.col = 1;
   ```
2. A proper LEFT join which filters the right table in the ON clause:

   ```
   select *
   from @t1 t1 
   left join @t2 t2
   on t1.id = t2.id 
   AND t2.col = 1;
   ```
3. An INNER JOIN.  This gives the same result as the first example--the LEFT JOIN with the filter for the right table in the Where clause:

   ```
   select *
   from @t1 t1 
   join @t2 t2
   on t1.id = t2.id
   where t2.col = 1;
   ```